# Identify id of modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, identify

How to identify id of modal window in this JS

```
$('.modal-Goalkeepers, .modal-Defenders, .modal-Midfielders, .modal-Forwards').on('show.bs.modal', function (data) {

   var id = {{here I want to know id of modal is now shown}}

});
```

Comment: can you show us the html you are working on, and by replace the keyword ID by class name as it's confusing for everyone

Comment: Use ID's as they are unique and limited to one per an element. The solution you're seeking may or may not give consistent results every time.

Comment: My falt. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this :

```
$('.modal-Goalkeepers, .modal-Defenders, .modal-Midfielders, .modal-Forwards').on('show.bs.modal', function(data) {

  var id = $(this).attr('class');
});
```

an example :

```js
$('.block1,.block2,.block3').click(function() {

  alert($(this).attr('class'));

});
```

```css
.block1,.block2,.block3 {
height:100px;
margin:20px;
background:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="block1"></div>
<div  class="block2"></div>
<div  class="block3"></div>
```

UPDATE : he need to get the class and not the id !

Comment: I receive 'undefined'(

Comment: you sure they have and id ?

Comment: I want to receive 'modal-Goalkeepers' or 'modal-Defenders' or another

Comment: oh, this is classes and not id, am gonna update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can access the ID through the keyword 'this'.
This will access the element that is being called by the event.

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: it is not work to modal windows. I receive 'undefined'.